# Why DensityPlot[If[expression<0,1,0]] produce this?

Tags: plotting

Here ContourPlot's result is reasonable. However I can't understand the result of DensityPlot. Please tell me the reason .
Thanks

```
xrange = {-0.0355, -0.0280};
yrange = {10, 60};
exp = -245 - 24471 x - 482010 x^2 - y;
DensityPlot[
 If[exp < 0, 1, 0], {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, yrange[[1]], 
  yrange[[2]]}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
ContourPlot[exp, {x, xrange[[1]], xrange[[2]]}, {y, xrange[[1]], 
  yrange[[2]]}, Contours -> {0, 10, -10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Result of DensityPlot] [image: Results of ContourPlot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation,

> With the default settings `Exclusions->Automatic` and `ExclusionsStyle->None`, `DensityPlot` breaks continuity in the density it displays at any discontinuity curve it detects.

Mathematica is detecting discontinuities where there aren't.  Set `Exclusions->None`

```
DensityPlot[If[exp<0,1,0],{x,xrange[[1]],xrange[[2]]},{y,yrange[[1]],yrange[[2]]},
PlotLegends->Automatic,Exclusions->None]
```

[image: grossdensityplot]

or better yet, use `RegionPlot`.  Seriously, look how good this looks!
[image: better]